# Please Upgrade Your Subversion Client.... How?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I opened up my eclipse today, after previously having a perfectly working Subclipse, and it decided to spontaneously break itself.

```
svn: E155021: The path 'xxx' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this working copy.
```

I tried completely uninstalling all of my subclipse packages in eclipse and then reinstalling them and it didn't fix it. Heres the installation link I used:

Subclipse 1.8.x Update Site - http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disconnected my project from the repo and deleted all my svn metadata, then reconnected it and it worked.

Comment: Those error messages come from Subversion itself.  You do not say what OS you are on, but keep in mind if you are not on Windows, then you need to install the Subversion native components for 1.7, including the JavaHL library.  See:  http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

Comment: Weird.. the problem came back and was fixed by.. restarting eclipse!

Answer (score 2):

This sometimes happens to me when I copy from an existing project under version control to another project under version control.  What you can try is a 'refresh/cleanup' or when you copy from one project to another, go to 'navigator' and then delete any svn metadata.  This data is typically found in .svn folders.

Answer (score 0):

I come across the same issue when I was trying to connect the previously disconnected project to the existing svn path.

I look close to it and found that, I was trying to connect the project in sub directory of svn project. Just point to actual svn path and problem solved!